# How to change colours of an "Icon"

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to change the colours of an `"Icon"` with `Colorize` and `ColorRules` but it seems to be ignoring the specified colours.

```
Colorize[EntityValue[Entity["Icon", "Camera"], "Image"], 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> Gray, 1 -> Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How to I change the colours as specified?

Comment: `Colorize[MorphologicalComponents[EntityValue[Entity["Icon","Camera"],"Image"]],ColorRules->{0->Gray,1->Green,2->Red}]` is your after?

Comment: Or kuba's solution `Colorize[Binarize[EntityValue[Entity["Icon","Camera"],"Image"]],ColorRules->{0->Gray,1->Green}]`

Comment: If you don't want to convert to an `Image`: `colorIcon[icon_,foreground_:Black, background_:White]:= FirstCase[InputForm[icon],Graphics[g___]:>Graphics[{foreground,g}, Background->background]]`.  `colorIcon[icon, Blue, Red]`

Comment: @chuy You should post as an answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I started by looking at the [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html) of an icon. (I use     Shallow to make if a bit easier to see the structure of the output.

```
icon = Entity["Icon", "Camera"]["Image"];   
Shallow[InputForm[icon],5]
(* Graphics[
    {FilledCurve[<<2>>], FilledCurve[<<2>>], FilledCurve[<<2>>],
     FilledCurve[<<2>>], FilledCurve[<<2>>], FilledCurve[<<2>>]}] *)
```

It's a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) expression with a List of [`FilledCurves`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FilledCurve.html).  We can change the background by using the [`Background`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Background.html) option for Graphics. The foreground color is changed by appending a Color (really any appropriate Directive) to the list of FilledCurves.

Here I use FirstCase to make the transformation.

```
colorIcon[icon_,foreground_:Black,background_:White]:=
 FirstCase[
   InputForm[icon], Graphics[g__]:> Graphics[{foreground,g},Background->background]
 ]

colorIcon[icon, Blue, Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This results in a Graphics expression again, so no need to convert to an Image.

Comment: And I was convinced that it was an `Image` and not `Graphics` because it's in the `"Image"` property ... +1!

Answer (score 11):

`ColorRules` is more useful for binary images.

```
Colorize[Binarize@Entity["Icon", "Camera"]["Image"], 
 ColorRules -> {0 -> Gray, 1 -> Green}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With that, you lose antialiasing.  For grayscale, use `ColorFunction` instead:

```
Colorize[Entity["Icon", "Camera"]["Image"], 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Gray, Green}, #] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Very informative.  I was under the impression the `"Icon"`s were strictly black and white.